# Android:Text after line break is not visible in a file(PrintWriter)

Tags: java, android

I am using PrintWriter to print some characters into the file. But when I use Println() to print a new line, the characters after new line are not visible.

Following is my code snippet

```
public void writeData(String data)
        {           
            //PrintWriter csvWriter;
            try
            {               
                csvWriter = new  PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));               
                csvWriter.print(data+","+"hello");
                //csvWriter.print("\r\n");
                csvWriter.println();
                csvWriter.print("world");
                csvWriter.close();                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

So in my file only the data & hello is visible. But "world" is not visible. I tried to print the new line using "\r\n" & "\n". But nothing is working.
Somebody please help me....Thanks!

Comment: I am storing the file in sdcard...

Comment: One more thing I observed that if i open that Excel sheet in pc then the word "world" is visible in a new line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
csvWriter.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Are you sure it is new line issue? Did you try by removing new line?

Comment: hey Probably you are correct... because when i removed the new line function the word "world" is not coming.. i tried the following  csvWriter.print(data+","+"hello"+","); csvWriter.print("world");....only data & "hello" is coming, but the word "world" is not coming..

Comment: try this, csvWriter.print(data+","+"hello"+"\n"+"world");

Comment: Strange, something wrong going with your program. Is it simple (or) complex one?

Comment: it is a simple one. I am just passing data(11) to the writeData function from activity & setting the file & directory name in the activity..

Comment: final try csvWriter.print(data+","+"hello"+"world"); Its late here, I am also running out of ideas.

Comment: if i write csvWriter.print(data+","+"hello"+","+"world"+","); den it is printing 11 "hello" "world"... but i want "world" to be printed in a new line...

Comment: One more thing I observed that if i open that Excel sheet in pc then the word "world" is visible in a new line...

Comment: I strongly suspect it is something with the file viewer. What happens if you add multiple lines? None of the lines showing up after first line

Comment: hey now it is working with "csvWriter.print("\r\n");"... but dont know how !!!! BTW thanx for your quality time... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using ... Line Seperator from system class

```
System.get("line.separator")
```

Comment: sorry... it is showing error. may be you are trying to say System.getProperty("line.separator")...

Comment: Ya... sorry my mistake... wrote in hurry!!

Comment: hmm.. but the output is same as before...sorry

Comment: are you saying about csvWriter.println(System.getProperty("line.separator")); ??  yes I tried this...

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush data.

```
csvWriter.println();
csvWriter.print("world");

//writes data from buffer to stream
csvWriter.flush();

csvWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  // open myfilename.txt for writing
  OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream("myfilename.txt",0));
  // write the contents on mySettings to the file
  out.write("Hello \n World");
  // close the file
  out.close();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
  //do something if an IOException occurs.
}
```

Comment: hey can you please tell me for what openFileOutput is used?? is it a user defined function??

Comment: try FileOutputStream in place of that!

Comment: may be you are trying to say FileOutputStream("myfilename.txt")... i tried this.. but it is only showing "hello"..